# Trigger oracle: whats wrong?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger, datagrip

This is my code:

```
create trigger TriggerAdresse1
    before INSERT
    on Adresse
    for each row
declare
    enthaelt boolean;
begin
    if ((Provinz in (select Name from Provinz2)) and (Laendercode in (select Laendercode from Provinz2))) then
        enthaelt := true;
    end if;
    if(enthaelt:=false) then
        rollback;
    end if;
end;
```

I am trying to cancel the insert if the attribute Provinz or Laendercode isn´t in the table Provinz2.
Datagrip says it´s not valid...

Thanks for your help!
Best regards

Comment: What is `Provinz`?

Comment: Provinz is an Attribute of Adresse

Comment: "Datagrip says it´s not valid..." is not a PL/SQL compilation error message. But there is no `if x in (select ...)` syntax in PL/SQL. Also, `if` conditions don't have brackets around them (though they won't cause compilation errors, they'll just irritate PL/SQL programmers).

Comment: Also, you can't use `rollback` in a trigger. That would roll back the whole transaction including any uncommitted changes made before the triggering statement, which is not allowed as it could potentially cause chaos. All you can do is raise an exception, which will cause the insert to fail with an error stack.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, William! We need to create an inspection in DataGrip:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-9944

Comment: @student123 can you please show what DataGrip highlights in your case as not valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A `BOOLEAN` value in Oracle can have **three** values: `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `NULL`, you did not initialize the variable.
- You have to refer to new values (by default with `:new`)
- By default a trigger cannot contain `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`

Your code must be this:

```
create trigger TriggerAdresse1
    before INSERT
    on Adresse
    for each row
declare
    enthaelt INTEGER;
begin

    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO enthaelt 
    FROM Provinz2
    WHERE Name = :new.Provinz
       AND Laendercode = :new.Laendercode;
    if enthaelt = 0 then
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Provinz oder Ländercode ungültig');
    end if;
end;
```

However, your requirement should be better implemented with FOREIGN KEY Constraint

```
alter table Adresse add constraint Provinz_FK FOREIGN KEY (Provinz) 
  references Provinz2 (Name);

alter table Adresse add constraint Laendercode_FK FOREIGN KEY (Laendercode) 
  references Provinz2(Laendercode);
```

Most likely `Laendercode` is not a UNIQUE key, but `Name+Laendercode` is. Then it would be this:

```
alter table Adresse add constraint Provinz_FK FOREIGN KEY (Provinz, Laendercode) 
  references Provinz2 (Name, Laendercode);
```

Comment: There is no `if var in (select)` construction in PL/SQL, even if you enclose it in double brackets.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson you are right, I correct my code.

Comment: A good candidate for the code inspection! https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-9944

Answer (score 0):

`if(enthaelt:=false) then`
Through this statement your intention is to perform a comparison however `:=` does the assignment. So whenever you are comparing, you should use as below:

```
if(enthaelt=false) then
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you intend to check the values being inserted so you really intend:

```
begin
    enthaelt := false;
    if ((:new.Provinz in (select Name from Provinz2)) and (:new.Laendercode in (select Laendercode from Provinz2))) then
        enthaelt := true;
    end if;
    if(enthaelt:=false) then
        rollback;
    end if;
end;
```

You also need to initialize the variable.

That said, the correct way to implement this logic is with a foreign key constraint.  It is sad that you are being taught to do this check with a trigger.